# Hiding Div Class based on Product Category

Tags: php, css

Running Wordpress and have Woocommerce installed on my website. I want to hide the div class 'quantity' from products in a specific product category.

All I have managed to do is hide 'quantity' from every product page.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pls post your code (which you said hiding quantity from every product page)

Comment: .quantity   {
 display:none
}